# Plotting pie charts in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, pie-chart

I want to plot a proper pie chart. However, most of the previous questions on this site were drawn from `stat = identity`. How can I plot a normal pie chart like graph 2 with the angle proportional to proportion of `cut`? I am using the `diamonds` data frame from ggplot2.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = cut)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

Graph 1
[image]

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, y=..prop.., fill = cut)) + 
    geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar(theta = "x")
```

Graph 2
[image]

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, fill = cut)) + 
    geom_bar()
```

Graph 3
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can first calculate the percentage of each `cut` group. I used the `dplyr` package for this task.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Calculate the percentage of each group
diamonds_summary <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  summarise(Percent = n()/nrow(.) * 100)
```

After that, we can plot the pie chart. `scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(cumsum(rev(diamonds_summary$Percent)), 1))` is to set the axis label based on cumulative percentage.

```
ggplot(data = diamonds_summary, mapping = aes(x = "", y = Percent, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(cumsum(rev(diamonds_summary$Percent)), 1)) +
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

Here is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = "", fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y")
```

It yields:

[image]

Comment: can you inline the photo in the post?

Answer (score 0):

I have created [ggpie](https://github.com/showteeth/ggpie) to better create pie, donut and rose pie plot, you can have a try.

This is [Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpie/vignettes/ggpie.html).

This is **circle label** and **out of pie**:

```
ggpie(data = diamonds, group_key = "cut", count_type = "full",
      label_info = "all", label_type = "circle",
      label_size = 4, label_pos = "out")
```

[image]