# R Make a pi chart of percentages by grouping things together

Tags: r

I have a large csv file with a list of people with different categories, for example gender. I want to create a pi chart that displays what percentage are male or female for example.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

mydata<-read.csv("data.csv")
gender <-mydata[,'gender']

pie(gender)
```

This is what i have and its telling me gender needs to be postive. help!

also how do i do it with ggplot2?

Comment: `pie(table(gender))`. (See what is `table(gender)`.)

Comment: thanks but how do i do it with ggplot2?

Comment: See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238098/plotting-pie-charts-in-ggplot2).