# cannot add pie chart in to a graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a pie chart instead of a table

```
method <- dataframe (stringsFactors=FALSE,method=c("violent","nonviolent"),accessiblepeople = (20000,60000)

usage <- dataframe (stringsFactors=FALSE,method=c("violent","nonviolent"),usage = (30%,70%)

ggplot(method, aes(x=method,y=accessiblepeople)+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ggtitle("")+ggpiechart())
```

Problem add piechart seems not working

Comment: Never heard of `ggpiechart`. Where is that from? + I am afraid your code is not working (missing parenthesis etc.). Check this post on how to make a pie chart with ggplot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238098/plotting-pie-charts-in-ggplot2

Comment: I want to add a piechart next to the ggplot, that is all

Comment: would tat work, that in one half there is a piechart and on the other hand histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plot_grid` from the package [cowplot](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) to place plots next to each other. I also specified a few features with `theme()` to remove the gray background so the final plot looks more cohesive.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

method <- data.frame(method = c("violent", "nonviolent"), 
                     accessiblepeople = c(20000,60000))

bar <- ggplot(method, aes(x = method, y = accessiblepeople, fill = method)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))

pie <- ggplot(method_df, aes(x="", y=accessiblepeople, fill=method)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + theme_void()

plot_grid(bar, pie)
```

[image]